# How to link static glibc in your makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I have compiled `glibc` which produced `libc.a` as a result. How can I link this in makefile. The makefile currently looks something like this.

```
CXX = g++

CXXFILES = file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp

CXXFLAGS =  -O3 -o prog -D_GNU_SOURCE
LIBS = -lpthread

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFILES) $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f prog *.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the libraries line to be like this:

```
LIBS =  -lc -lpthread
```

If `libc.a` is not in the usual directory, change the library path to look in your directory first.

Answer (score 0):

Modify it like this. Replace *LIBPATH* with the path where `libc.a` is placed.

```
CXX = g++

CXXFILES = file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp

CXXFLAGS =  -O3 -o prog -D_GNU_SOURCE
LIBS = -LIBPATH/libc.a -lpthread

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFILES) $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f prog *.o
```